# previousBlockHash values by cli and SDK are different

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

previousBlockHash value from CLI is different form that from SDK

this is the block header queried by cli
(fetch block by cli and translate it by configtxlator)

```
"number"       : "41210"
"previous_hash": "SncQcGaSskVxSuP3dppyW5Mru1gLIfPjv9pxwnHvQ0E="
"data_hash"    : "Kj8vkGMHtdmQXVDdvGg3Kk+IjAYH9NJELrakXoSCJ+U="
```

And this is that from SDK

```
Block Number  : 41210
Previous Hash : 4a7710706692b245714ae3f7769a725b932bbb580b21f3e3bfda71c271ef4341
Data Hash     : 2a3f2f906307b5d9905d50ddbc68372a4f888c0607f4d2442eb6a45e848227e5
```

As seen, the format of the PreviousHash and DataHash looks different.
I guess those from CLI are encrypted and those of SDK are plain and actual data.

I want to know how to get the same value from those of CLI.
Is there any decryption method?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

No.... it's just that CLI encodes in base64 and the SDK in hex-decimal:

Put it the CLI output here and you'll see it's the same. 
https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex